# Dataset with many NA's and creation of correlation matrix

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data

Should i *remove all the NA's and outliers* from my dataset before continue to the creation of my correlation matrix ?? Because I can see from the lines I have run in R Studio that without do anything of these processes , I get full of NA's in the extracted correlation matrix table !

My code:

```r
new_obj <- list(all_fear_fail = c(31.2479995806889, NA, NA, 
        35.0430788647046, 
        NA, NA), all_high_stat_entre = c(72.8056631518627, NA, NA, 
        75.6879341950206, 
        NA, NA), patience = c(NA, NA, -0.201360121369362, NA, NA, 
        NA), 
            risktaking = c(NA, NA, 0.120764262974262, NA, NA, NA), 
            posrecip = c(NA, 
            NA, 0.2896409034729, NA, NA, NA), negrecip = c(NA, NA, 
            0.254712462425232, 
            NA, NA, NA))
    
new_obj <- data.frame(new_obj)

#correlations
new_obj<-new_obj[,c(1:14)]
res <- cor(new_obj)
round(res, 2)
    
library(corrplot)
corrplot(res, type = "upper", order = "hclust", 
            tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45)
    
library("PerformanceAnalytics")
chart.Correlation(new_obj, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

Your opinion ? ( I suppose yes I must do it ...)

Comment: I voted to migrate this question because it's not really a question about R so much as it is a question about the appropriate procedure for dealing with missing data in correlation matrices.  That said, when you could do `res <- cor(new_obj, use="pairwise.complete.obs")`, which would pairwise instead of listwise delete the data.

Comment: Have a look at the `?cor` help page. The `use` argument offers several options for which observations to automatically remove based on missingness.

Comment: As for outliers, that's a more fraught issue. How would you intend to define "outlier"?

Comment: It depends on what you will use your correlation matrix for.  For instance, if you plan to apply procedures that require it to be a valid correlation matrix, then using only pairwise deletion procedures could mess that up.  Please describe your application and the actual problem you are trying to solve.